# Determining the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series I have is: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n} \int^{\pi}_{0} (x+n\pi)^{-p}\sin{(x)} dx$$ where $p>0$.

We can use the alternating series test where $$a_{n} = \int^{\pi}_{0} (x+n\pi)^{-p}\sin{(x)} dx$$ When $x\in[0,\pi]$ we have $a_{n} > 0$ And can easily show it tends to zero by comparison but how do we show that $a_{n}$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $a_n$ is decreasing, you can just notice that the integrand is non-negative, $x + (n+1) \pi > x + n \pi$, and therefore
$$\int_0^\pi (x + (n+1)\pi)^{-p} \sin(x) \, dx \le \int_0^\pi (x + n \pi)^{-p} \sin(x) \, dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin x}{(x+n\pi)^p}<\frac{\sin x}{[x+(n+1)\pi]^p}$$
for each $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: Your inequality has the wrong direction.